# django-admin startproject webproject . The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: django, visual-studio

When I tried following the instructions to create my Django project with these steps:

[Create the Django project](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django)

```
In the VS Code Terminal where your virtual environment is activated, run the following command:

django-admin startproject web_project .
```

It didn't work.

Ran in (venv):  django-admin startproject webproject .

Got: The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, You have installed latest version of `django` installed in your working virtual environment.

`pip install -U django`

So activate virtual env and run the command mentioned above.

`django-admin startproject web_project`

Comment: To check the version: 'import django

print(django.get_version())'However, "django-admin startproject web_project' did not work

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, instead just type:

```
python -m startproject testapp
```

And it should work.